# Uploading an image in express just hangs

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

`html`:

```
  <form method='post' action='upload_bg' enctype="multipart/form-data">
  <input type='file' name='fileUploaded'>
  <input type='submit'>
```

My `index.js`

```
app.route('/upload_bg')
    .post(function (req, res) {
        var fstream;
        req.busboy.on('file', function (fieldname, file, filename) {
          console.log(filename);
            fstream = fs.createWriteStream(__dirname + '/imgs/' + "latest_upload.jpg");
            file.pipe(fstream);
            fstream.on('close', function () {
                res.redirect('back');
            });
        });
    });
```

My variables:

```
var express = require('express');
var busboy = require('connect-busboy');
var path = require('path');
var fs = require('fs-extra');
```

So the user clicks the button, selects an image, and selects submit. This hit's my route `upload_bg`. I've had it working before, and I changed a few things around but I'm unable to understand why it isn't working. I look in the network tab and the request is just pending indefinitely.

Comment: You only return something when the `fstream` is closed, hence, should an error occur you won't be returning anything from the request and the request will just be pending. This most likely means that you have an issue within your route. Once you upload a file is the filename being printed in the console? Have you made any permission changes in the directories?

Comment: @LennartHase So I was reading through the docs and found I was missing `req.pipe(req.busboy);`. I've added it in, the new error i'm getting looks like `Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, open /path-to-my-image/image.jpg`

Comment: @LennartHase I do hit the `console.log(filename);` now, but after that it errors out

Comment: This looks to be part of a different bit of code, I don't see that file path `/path-to-my-image/image.jpg` anywhere in the above code? Looks like some placeholder code you may have missed?

Comment: @LennartHase sorry, no the `path-to-my-image` I replaced, it's just basically my local path, so `/Users/me/Desktop/projectDirectory/latest_upload.jpg.jpg`

Comment: hmmmmm, my best guess is, assuming the directory exists that is shown (triple checking never hurt, just in case :P), it could be a permissions issue, make sure the folder has sufficient permissions so that your node app can write to it

Comment: Okay, I've gone further down the worm whole, my path for the images was a `/` off, i've changed that. NOW my error is `Error: Can't set headers after they are sent.` When I hit my `console.log(filename);` it get hit three times, in my console window so i'm assuming I need to return?

Answer (score 1):

Here is my simple solution using express-fileupload module:
First intall express fileupload module using following command:

```
 npm install express-fileupload
```

HTML page code:

```
<html>
<body>
<form ref='uploadForm' 
  id='uploadForm' 
  action='http://localhost:3000/upload_bg' 
  method='post' 
  encType="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="sampleFile" />
    <input type='submit' value='Upload!' />
</form>     
</body>
</html>
```

node server code:
server.js:

```
var express=require('express');

var app = express();

var fileUpload = require('express-fileupload');

// default options
app.use(fileUpload());

app.post('/upload_bg', function(req, res) {
  if (!req.files)
    return res.status(400).send('No files were uploaded.');

  // The name of the input field (i.e. "sampleFile") is used to retrieve the uploaded file
  let sampleFile = req.files.sampleFile;

  // Use the mv() method to place the file somewhere on your server
  // Make sure 'imgs' folder is already created inside current directory otherwise it will throw error where this server.js file is placed
  sampleFile.mv(__dirname + '/imgs/latest_upload.jpg', function(err) {
    if (err)
      return res.status(500).send(err);

    res.send('File uploaded!');
  });
});

app.listen(3000,function(){
    console.log("App listening on port 3000")
});
```

Hope this will help. For complete code refer https://github.com/richardgirges/express-fileupload

Answer (score 0):

I would personally re-style your code a little bit. And I would use `ajax`. Here is some example code:

#### `index html`:

```
<button class="btn btn-lg upload-btn" type="button">Upload image</button>
<input id="upload-input" type="file" name="uploads[]" multiple="multiple">
```

#### `client js`:

This can/should be inside of `index.html`

```
$('.upload-btn').on('click', function (){
    $('#upload-input').click();
    $('.progress-bar').text('0%');
    $('.progress-bar').width('0%');
});

$('#upload-input').on('change', function(){

  var files = $(this).get(0).files;

  if (files.length > 0){
    // create a FormData object which will be sent as the data payload in the
    // AJAX request
    var formData = new FormData();

    // loop through all the selected files and add them to the formData object
    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
      var file = files[i];

      // add the files to formData object for the data payload
      formData.append('uploads[]', file, file.name);
    }

    $.ajax({
      url: '/upload',
      type: 'POST',
      data: formData,
      processData: false,
      contentType: false,
      success: function(data){
          console.log('upload successful!\n' + data);
      },
    });

  }
});
```

#### `server js`:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require('path');
var formidable = require('formidable');
var fs = require('fs');
var l;

//... other code here


app.get('/upload', function(req, res){
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, 'index.html'));
});

app.post('/upload', function(req, res){

  var form = new formidable.IncomingForm();

  form.multiples = true;

  form.uploadDir = path.join(__dirname, '/uploads');

  form.on('file', function(field, file) {
    fs.readdir('uploads/', function(err, items) {
        console.log(items.length);
        l = items.length
        console.log(l);
        fs.rename(file.path, "uploads/"+l+".jpg", function(err) {
            if ( err ) console.log('ERROR: ' + err);
        });
    });
  });

  form.on('error', function(err) {
    console.log('An error has occured: \n' + err);
  });

  form.on('end', function() {
    res.end('success');
  });

  form.parse(req);

});
```

Hope this helps!